Unable to make changes to read-only postgresql.properties file within a pod
I am currently trying to configure trino cli in my EKS cluster, in order to query my Postgres DB on RDS. I am trying to make changes to the following properties file
postgresql.properties
connector.name=postgresql
connection-url=jdbc:postgresql://jdbc:postgresql://mani-acme-read-replica.c7tubtqdas.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com:5432/dev
connection-user=manacme
connection-password=sbfhjakl2sd

The connection URL is supposed to be
connection-url=jdbc:postgresql://mani-acme-read-replica.c7tubtqdas.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com:5432/dev

so that it is able to parse URL and read the RDS data.
Every time I try a different route, I keep encountering the same read-only file error. I would like to understand where I am going to wrong and if there's any specific fix for this. Any help would be appreciated.
rraj@loggers-MacBook-Pro ~ % kubectl run temp-pod --image=trino:latest --restart=Never -n trino

pod/temp-pod created
rraj@loggers-MacBook-Pro ~ % kubectl exec -it temp-pod -n trino -- /bin/sh

error: unable to upgrade connection: container not found ("temp-pod")
rraj@loggers-MacBook-Pro ~ % kubectl get pods -n trino                                         
NAME                                          READY   STATUS             RESTARTS      AGE
my-trino-trino-coordinator-544dfb8986-tpx2f   1/1     Running            1 (13m ago)   36m
my-trino-trino-worker-57db54fc5b-dlq8p        1/1     Running            0             167m
my-trino-trino-worker-57db54fc5b-vs9qx        1/1     Running            0             167m
temp-pod                                      0/1     ImagePullBackOff   0             21s
trino-cli                                     1/1     Running            0             112m
trino-cli-6f5897c656-qt8fv                    1/1     Running            1 (19m ago)   80m
rraj@loggers-MacBook-Pro ~ % kubectl delete pod temp-pod
Error from server (NotFound): pods "temp-pod" not found
rraj@loggers-MacBook-Pro ~ % kubectl get pods -n trino  
NAME                                          READY   STATUS             RESTARTS      AGE
my-trino-trino-coordinator-544dfb8986-tpx2f   1/1     Running            1 (13m ago)   37m
my-trino-trino-worker-57db54fc5b-dlq8p        1/1     Running            0             167m
my-trino-trino-worker-57db54fc5b-vs9qx        1/1     Running            0             167m
temp-pod                                      0/1     ImagePullBackOff   0             46s
trino-cli                                     1/1     Running            0             112m
trino-cli-6f5897c656-qt8fv                    1/1     Running            1 (20m ago)   80m
rraj@loggers-MacBook-Pro ~ % kubectl delete pod temp-pod -n trino --grace-period=0 --force

Warning: Immediate deletion does not wait for confirmation that the running resource has been terminated. The resource may continue to run on the cluster indefinitely.
pod "temp-pod" force deleted
rraj@loggers-MacBook-Pro ~ % kubectl get pods -n trino                                    
NAME                                          READY   STATUS    RESTARTS      AGE
my-trino-trino-coordinator-544dfb8986-tpx2f   1/1     Running   1 (13m ago)   37m
my-trino-trino-worker-57db54fc5b-dlq8p        1/1     Running   0             168m
my-trino-trino-worker-57db54fc5b-vs9qx        1/1     Running   0             168m
trino-cli                                     1/1     Running   0             113m
trino-cli-6f5897c656-qt8fv                    1/1     Running   1 (20m ago)   80m
rraj@loggers-MacBook-Pro ~ % kubectl exec -it my-trino-trino-coordinator-544dfb8986-tpx2f -n trino -- /bin/sh

sh-5.1$ cat /etc/trino/catalog/postgresql.properties
connector.name=postgresql
connection-url=jdbc:postgresql://jdbc:postgresql://mani-acme-read-replica.c7tubtqdas.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com:5432/dev
connection-user=maniacme
connection-password=sbfhjakl2sd

sh-5.1$ cat > /etc/trino/catalog/new_postgresql.properties
sh: /etc/trino/catalog/new_postgresql.properties: Read-only file system
sh-5.1$ sed -i '/connection-url/d' /etc/trino/catalog/postgresql.properties
sed: couldn't open temporary file /etc/trino/catalog/sed8XFnnd: Read-only file system
sh-5.1$ sudo vi /etc/trino/catalog/postgresql.properties
sh: sudo: command not found
sh-5.1$ echo "connection-url=jdbc:postgresql://mani-acme-read-replica.c7tubtqdas.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com:5432/dev" > /etc/trino/catalog/postgresql.properties
sh: /etc/trino/catalog/postgresql.properties: Read-only file system
sh-5.1$ %   

                                                                                         


You shouldn't normally be editing things in containers using kubectl exec.  Among other problems, it's possible for a Node to be deleted outside your control, which will cause any Pods to be deleted and recreated, which will lose your local changes.  Do you need to inject these settings via a ConfigMap, or does the underlying image support configuration via environment variables?

I agree with David, this issue can be solved with either a ConfigMap or environment variable. For a read only file system, you can't write.
Do you have control over the resource manifest?

I tried the ConfigMap approach and it still didn't go through. Instead I passed the postgres properties in the trino deployment and passed the yaml file to helm. That worked.
